# pushViewController resulting in different behaviour when called in different scenarios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following code which works from my 'scorer' class apart from in the following scenario. I push another viewcontroller `editscore`, in that view do something, return to `scorer` pop the editscore and then in some circumstances i will end up pushing my legorderviewcontroller as shown below (it calls the same code). Only this time the new navigation bar is written over the top of the 'scorer' navigation bar and `legorderviewcontroller` doesn't appear. Does anyone know why this happens in this scenario?

```
legOrderViewController *controller = [[legOrderViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
controller.leg = self.leg;
controller.delegate = self;
controller.match =self.match;
controller.set = self.set;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
controller.playerChangeArray =  playerOrder;
[controller release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if you call pushViewController too fast after performing popviewcontroller WITH an animation. I ran into that issue once, disabling the animation solved it.

Comment: Superb! I would never have thought of changing that.